# Redmine Plugin. Add action in ProjectsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm creating plugin for redmine. I need to add action in projects controller. 
I made ​​a patch for ProjectsControllers

```
  module ProjectsControllerPatch
  def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
  end
  module InstanceMethod
     def new_method
     end
  end
end

# Add module to Issue
ProjectsController.send(:include, ProjectsControllerPatch)
```

And added route in routes.rb:

```
get 'new_method', :to => 'projets#new_method'
```

But I have 404 error on this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define route like this:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'issue/:issue_id/something/:action/:id', to: 'something#new_some', as: 'fancy_route'
end
```

After that register this route in your plugin:

```
project_module :my_plugin do
  permission :my_plugin, { :my_plugin => [:fancy_route] },:public => true
end
```

Live example from iCalendar plugin:

```
project_module :redmine_icalendar do
  permission :redmine_icalendar, {:redmine_icalendar => [:index, :show, :list]}, :public => true
  permission :redmine_icalendar, {:redmine_icalendar => [:edit, :new, :destroy]}, :require => :member    
end
```

Comment: It didn't help me. Maybe, Maybe I misunderstood how to register permission.

Comment: Is :my_plugin a name of my plugin? And What does it mean { :my_plugin => [:my_plugin] }

Comment: Sorry, crappy example. This is more clear: { :my_plugin => [:index, :show] } I have edited my answer with correct code and live example from iCalendar plugin.

Comment: It didn't help me too. Could you give me link to iCalendar plugin src

Comment: it's some kind of internal plugin ) For learning I was using this plugin http://www.redminebacklogs.net/ it's quite complex and has all examples I wanted